# Make routes upperscore instead of underscore?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Very basic and maybe I missed it, but instead of doing something like `sign_up` for my routes, how can I do `sign-up`? This is assuming I have these route like this:

```
get "/sign_up" => "devise/registrations#new"
```

It doesn't work for me if I change it to: `get "/sign-up"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
match "/sign-up" => "devise/registrations#new", :as => :sign_up
```

Unfortunately ActionDispatch works best with underscores.  So you might try compromising by keeping with convention for the `sign_up_path` helper and using the dash in the URL